# Accessing rails application from another computer which is on different network

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can I acces my rails application which is running with `rails s` right now from another network?
I am using a dynamic IP address, and if I just go to http://whatismyipaddress.com/ and enter the IP provided there into the browser and end it with :3000,  it will give a unable to connect error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a gem called [localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/). The easiest way to share localhost web servers to the rest of the world.

```
$ gem install localtunnel
$ localtunnel -k ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 3000
```

You should see something like this:

```
Port 3000 is now publicly accessible from http://8bv2.localtunnel.com ...
```